# Copy Command Redshift putting quotes around super column values

Tags: amazon-redshift

I created a table

```
create table test.array_test    
(
id integer,
super_field super
)
```

When I insert data rows like below

```
insert into test.array_test
values (2,'[1,2,3,10]');

insert into test.array_test
values (3,array(1,2,3,10));
```

When I run a select I get rows like below where id=2 is putting quotes around the outside of the array

```
id  super_field
--  -----------
2   "[1,2,3,10]"
3   [1,2,3,10]
```

I am able to unnest the id = 3 with below sql but am not getting any rows back for id = 2

```
select t.id,  t1
from   test.array_test t,
      t.super_field t1

id  t1
--  --
3   1
3   2
3   3
3   10
```

Is it possible to turn the id = 2 into an array without the quotes?  The copy table command in redshift is putting the values into the table with quotes around them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example

```
insert into test.array_test
values (2,'[1,2,3,10]');
```

'[1,2,3,10]' is a single string.  It is being stored as a single value in your super column.

You need to insert the super data you desire not just a string.  The easiest way is

```
insert into test.array_test
values (2,JSON_PARSE('[1,2,3,10]'));
```

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/ingest-super.html for more information on this process.

Comment: I used part of above as a basis then below to get the values from id = 2

select *
from  
 (
  select id,json_parse(super_field::text) super_field
  from   test.array_test
 ) arr,
 arr.super_field t1

If I only using insert to show example I am using redshift copy command to import the data so I don't have the option to put json_parse round values when inserting

Comment: I'm glad you got this working. You didn't specify the file format of your S3 objects so I posted the link as this page gives examples for COPY from many different source file types.  It can get challenging to get the source file into exactly the correct format for direct ingestion of super data especially text for CSV/text.  So your solution may be optimal if you don't have direct ability to modify the format of these files.

Answer (score 0):

I used part of above as a basis then below to get the values from id = 2

```
select *
from  
    (
        select id,json_parse(super_field::text) super_field
        from   test.array_test
    ) arr,
    arr.super_field t1
```

I am only using insert to show example I am using redshift copy command to import the data so I don't have the option to put json_parse round values when inserting